# Correct usage with commas and conjunctions

Tags: meaning, differences, american-english, commas, conjunctions

1. He won the race, though he never made the grade.
2. He was charged with fraud; though, these charges were dropped in court.

Any difference in usage with *though* in these examples? In the sense one looks correct with the semi-colon (more formal), whilst the other does not.

Also, any difference between 3 & 4 in terms of commas around the name.

3. Clair's mum, Debra, sadly lost her battle with an illness.
4. James' stunning wife Sarah walked down the aisle on the wedding day.

Comment: (2) is ungrammatical, and the comma would be usual though by no means mandatory in (1). But (3) and (4) make this IMO a valid question here. I'd echo the examples, using commas around the appositive in (3) but not in (4). It's as if one should _know_ who James's wife is, so no 'pause to consider' is valid.

Comment: In sentence #2 (the first one though), "though" looks out of place; I'd expected "however" or something.

Comment: The first two sentences are about something quite different than the last two sentences. This should really be split up into two different questions.

Comment: On checking, possible duplicate (sentences (3) and (4)) of [Do nonrestrictive appositives always require commas?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222201/do-nonrestrictive-appositives-always-require-commas) where the answer 'Some would say yes but others would disagree' seems valid. The question/s here concerning (1) and (2) are not suitable for ELU.

Answer (score 1):

"Though" is an interchangeable conjunction with "even though" and "although", and even though it sounds weird to some, the first usage (1.) is correct, while the usage with the semi-colon is debatable.

Examples 3 and 4 are both correct. In 3, you have the appositive set off by commas, either because of a pause or because of its lack of restrictiveness, or both. However, I would recommend putting commas around "Sarah" in the second example, as it can be a non-restrictive appositive also. Some may say that the lacking of commas prompts one to think that there are multiple wives in context. That might be reaching, so let's just say that the pause sounds better; "Jame's stunning wife, Sarah, walked down the aisle on the wedding day." This is purely a suggestion.